# Matrix with integer entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

The determinant of a given square matrix $A$, with rational entries, equals 1. It is known that all entries of $A^{2015}$ are integers. Is it true that all entries of $A$ are integers?

**My attemt**: I've tried to construct a counter example but failed. I believe it's true but don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 18):

Let $A = \left(
 \begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & \frac{1}{2015} \\
 0  & 1\end{array} \right)$, then $A^{2015} = \left(
 \begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 \\
 0  & 1\end{array} \right)$.

Comment: Did you use the diagonal form to compute $A^{2015}$?

Comment: No; just compute $A, A^2, A^3$, then you can easily observe this.

Comment: @prometheus21 what "diagonal form" would that be?  $A$ is not diagonalizable.

Comment: @prometheus21 In general, observe $\begin{pmatrix} 1&x\\0&1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1&y \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1&x+y\\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix}$.